# Preventing keyboard dismissal on form submit on mobile view of web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I am creating a PHP Javascript chat application. Whenever I click on send button it simply slides down / dismisses the keyboard. If I need to send a new message I again have to tap on the `textarea` field to make the keyboard slide up / appear for typing. This unwanted keyboard dismissal after every send is annoying. I haven't included any code here as this is not a coding bug that is occurring from my script. This seems to be the default behavior of the web apps that dismisses the keyboard when the form's submit button is clicked.

The gif below shows what is happening. How can I prevent this default behavior?

https://gifyu.com/image/ABYn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is every time you click on the send button, the `textarea` loses focus. Once the `textarea` loses focus, the on screen keyboard has no reason to be visible. You can solve this by adding a javascript code to your click event so that the on screen keyboard remains there every time after the submit button is clicked.

You can use something like:

```
const form = document.querySelector(".typing-area"),
inputField = form.querySelector(".input-field"),
sendBtn = form.querySelector("button");

// PREVENT FORM SUBMISSION BY PAGE REFRESH (THE DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR)
form.onsubmit = (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault();
}

// ADD FOCUS TO INPUT FIELD BY DEFAULT (ON PAGE LOAD)
inputField.focus();

// PREVENT INPUT FIELD FROM LOOSING FOCUS AFTER SEND BUTTON IS CLICKED
sendBtn.onclick = ()=> {
  inputField.focus();
}
```